# compile and install boost 1.34.1 in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: c++, ubuntu, boost

Recently, I am working in hypertable 0.9.0.0, so I first must build boost 1.34.1.

I am sure I nearly follow the index.html in doc of boost directory.First,use `./confiure` and then input `sudo make install`. In the manual, it tells the two command can help me install all the libraries by default. However, when I am compiling the hypertable source code, it occurs this error meessage

`CMake Error at cmake/FindBoost.cmake:151 (MESSAGE):
  Boost thread library was not found.
Call Stack (most recent call first):`

I have tried to modified the compile options when compiling boost. For example, use `./configure --with-libraries=program_options...`, but I still found the compiler failed doing many things when compiling. Of course, the boost libraies I needed cannot be found in the default directory `/usr/local/lib`.

The fact is that I cannot make it with myself, so I am eager to ask you guys' help. Thank you all in advance!

Comment: I believe that 1.34.1 is five years old or so. Why don't you just install boost 1.46 from ubuntu repository?

Comment: Because the README of hypertable 0.9.0.0 tells the version of boost is 1.34.1. I will try your suggestion later.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
   sudo apt-get install libboost-all-dev
```

This is much faster than building boost yourself.

Comment: This will not install boost 1.34, it will install the latest version. And this is not what he asking.

Comment: The fact shows that it is a better idea to try the later version of hypertable. After all, there are always some unexpected errors if I was trying to build the 'older' source code on the 'newer' platform. Thank you very much!

Comment: sudo apt-get install libboost1.34-all-dev